# dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, dyld

Error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/n.framework/n
>   Referenced from: /Users/hunterp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Bundle/Application//Demo.app/Demo
>     Reason: image not found

I followed every answer in this stackoverflow question: [iOS app with framework crashed on device, dyld: Library not loaded, Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta)

AND heres my build settings:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to select executable_path and press Delete
   [image]
2. Also try the same with Library Search Paths and Header Search Paths
3. If you have 2 targets try to edit your pod file:

   ```
   target :MainTarget, :exclusive => true do
   link_with ['Target1']

     pod 'SomePod'

   end

   target :SecondTarget, :exclusive => true do
   link_with ['Target2']

     pod 'SomePod'

   end
   ```

and run in the terminal : pod update

4. Also set Pods Debug and Release configuration to None
   [image]

Comment: why should @executable_path be deleted in step one? You mean the Runpath Search path should be empty?

Comment: @AnanthKamath the path will be not empty, it will be default.

Comment: I was forgetting the targets in podfile, thanks ! Also for a cleaner pod, I would recommend this accepted answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907073/10202308

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that there is something else wrong in your build settings as your error message contains extraneous slashes between directories

```
/Users/hunterp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Bundle/Application//Demo.app/Demo Reason: image not found
                                                      ^^                                  ^^
```

(which the syntax highlighting nicely points out when I format as code ;))

When searching for the framework, it's possible that when it goes up a directory (with ..) it's parsing one of those `//`s not as you expect.

I'd check your header, framework and library search paths for entries that contain slashes where they are not needed, especially if they reference `$(BUILDDIR)/`<sup>1</sup> or similar

---

<sup>1. I can't remember the actual environment variables</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think the error

> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/n.framework/n ...

shows the Runpath Search Paths is set to be "@executable_path/../Frameworks".
Go to "Build Settings"->"Runpath Search Paths", delete "@executable_path/../Frameworks" if exists, then add "@executable_path/Frameworks".