# How to add one pod to multiple targets in Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

Right now I need to add LiveSDK to multiple targets. Please see below:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

target :CalDoKit do
    pod 'LiveSDK'
end

pod 'Google-API-Client/Calendar'
pod 'LiveSDK'
```

As you can see the LiveSDK pod added twice. And I am getting warning from the console output when I run the application: `One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

What's the correct way to add one pod to multiple targets?

New code:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

link_with 'CalDo', 'CalDoKit'

pod 'LiveSDK'

target :CalDo do
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
end
```

But I am getting warning:

```
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `TestKit` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project

Comment: @JakubVano I couldn't understand the link_with. For example: `link_with 'MyApp', 'MyOtherApp'`. It didn't say which framework should included so both MyApp and MyOtherApp share the same framework.

Answer (score 0):

- Solution 1:

Remove that 'target :xx do ... end' and add pod without defining targets. It will add the pod for all targets.

- Solution 2:

Delete that podfile and run pod init command from terminal. this will make a new podfile with all the targets used in the project and then you can add pods separately for each target

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the `Podfile`

```
target :AnotherTarget do
   pod 'LiveSDK'
end
```

**EDIT**

This is the final `Podfile` source

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

target :CalDoKit do
    pod 'LiveSDK'
end

target :OtherTarget do
    pod 'LiveSDK'
end
```

If you execute `pod init` console command on your project folder, it will create the `Podfile` with built in code.

See here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. Please read my question completely.

Comment: Possible duplication of [Multiple Target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project)