# AFNetworking (installed with CocaPods) throws errors after change of build target

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

When I build project to real device (iPhone 5) everything works fine. When I change target to any simulator I see:

[image]

Same configuration of PodFile is running without problems for my friends. It stoped working without resonable reason (i.e. changing podfile or AFNetworking)

my podfile is:

```
# Networking
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

.

.

.

-------------------------------- ANSWER --------------------------------

In my case deleting xcode derived data and reset iPhone simulator settings helped

.

.

.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have picked up duplicate symbols, probably two similar installations of that pod.  Try a clean build.

Comment: Didn't help. Also deleting and reinstalling of all pod filed didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can create different targets in your Podfile.

Check here: [How do I specify multiple targets in my podfile for my Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project)