# PCH Files Error, with two targets

Tags: ios, xcode7, precompiled-headers

I have a project with multiple targets. For one target app is building fine. But for another target I am getting File not found for the frameworks added inside Pre-Compiled Header file.

https://gyazo.com/63b1b25eabaff73eb48314dbd25e2b20

I've tried adding the path in the Search Paths for Frameworks, Headers and Library but it's not working.

Please, help me out how to fix this.

Thanks and Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Yes, I have and project is building for only one target and giving me File not found error for other targets.

Comment: If you used pods and not mentioned all the targets of your project then by default pods chooses the first target. You  have to mention all targets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project

see this 

link_with 'targetname', 'targetname',....

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan thanks for your kind help, It really solved the issue. Many thanks for this. Please add your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Nice to see your problem solved :)