# GGLCore/GGLCore.h file not found Analytics.h?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working on objective c google analytics, I am getting error "GGLCore/GGLCore.h file not found Analytics.h". I followed this like to implement the code developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

[image: Image 1]

Pod file.

[image: Pod file image]

Comment: I encounter the same warning but my case is that I forget to add pods to my unit test. After adding pods to target 'MyProjectTest' and pod install, problem solved.

To organize your pods with multiple targets, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907073/7562022).

Comment: Thank u for your comment, i solved my self successfully.

Comment: Would you like to share your case and how you solve it? Somebody might need it.

Comment: Ok, i will share it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially i opened AppNamme.xcodeproj. But i used pods in my project. Later i opened AppName.xcworkspace.

And there is second chance to get this error is...

I manually added SDK. Later i removed all files and added through pods. Now the error gone...