# how can i create a framework from existing project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

i have a huge project written in objective c with many pods in it and i would like to export the entire thing as a framework. is it possible? i have never did such thing before. my project also has a big assets library and frameworks inside of it like Firebase/Fabric/Facebook and much more. how will i handle the info.plist file of the existing project in the new framework?

i have tried this tutorial

https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial

but it doesn't mention having previous pods in my existing project.

Comment: In short: Create a framework target, make all source code files a member of the new target, add the new target as target to the podfile. For everything else the tutorial should work.

Comment: do you mean i need to do nothing with my pods? it will make automatic dependencies? i should add just my source files? also - how do i add a target to a podfile? like this: `target 'SomeProject' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end`  ?

Comment: "it will make automatic dependencies": that is what CocoaPods is, an "automatic" dependency tool.  how do i add a target to a podfile: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14906534/1457385

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @user1974368 I am stuck in a similar problem? Can you please guide me how to convert my project into a framework???

Comment: @shallowThought Can u provide an example code or describe the process briefly?