# Install cocoapods for some target only

Tags: ios, cocoapods

How can I install cocoapods for some targets only?

pod 1 and pod 2 -> target 1 and target 2

pod 3 -> target 1

pod 4 -> target 2

Any idea regarding this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project ? Show your podfile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify multiple targets in my podfile for my Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project)