# Import works in some targets, not others - No such Module

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

In my pods I have `pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2.5'` and in the `App` target this pod is imported without problem. I also have an `AppSDK` target, and an `AppSDK` folder. In my `AppSDK` folder I have a file called `LocationMedata`. If I set it's target to `App` I have no problem. However if I also toggle `AppSDK` (or if I only toggle `AppSDK`) I get a "No such module error". I do not remotely understand why this is the case. To me this seems like either a glitch or horridly unintuitive feature of Xcode, but I would love to be shown otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Every pod library is associated with 1 target ( look to the podFile structure ) You need to either tick target membership of the library you have to that other target or add it inside the podFile  under that target and do pod install

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am unclear where I find the 'pod library'. What do I click?

Comment: https://www.natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/  && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project

Comment: ticking option is handy if the library contains a few files but for many look to above comments