# The test runner failed to load the test bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, realm, cocoapods, xctest

I'm developing a cocoa touch framework and I'm importing "RealmSwift" using CocoaPods. The project builds successfully but the tests fails to load.
I'm getting the following error:

> xctest (97035) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation
>   never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted.
>   (Underlying error: The test runner failed to load the test bundle.
>   Executable cannot be loaded for some other reason, such as a problem
>   with a library it depends on or a code signature/entitlements
>   mismatch.))

Crash log:

```
2019-02-27 17:35:44.197599+0400 xctest[12408:121075] The bundle “MyFrameworkTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2019-02-27 17:35:44.197835+0400 xctest[12408:121075] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/zakaria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-cltpexonmtkefveximwygxbkkcrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameworkTests.xctest/MyFrameworkTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm
  Referenced from: /Users/zakaria/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyFramework-cltpexonmtkefveximwygxbkkcrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameworkTests.xctest/MyFrameworkTests
  Reason: image not found)
```

I tried every solution I could find online, but to no avail.

It's worth mentioning that this works successfully in a iOS project, the problem occurs only in a cocoa touch framework.

My podfile is as follow:

```
target 'Framework' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.13.1'

  target 'FrameworkTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

I'm using Xcode version: 10.1
and CocoaPods version: 1.6.0

Comment: Are you facing issue with all the test cases or just one test case?

Comment: @Satyam The test bundle fails to load. So no cases were tested.

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @iKushal Yes, please check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the podfile that worked for me:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

def shared
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.18.0'
end

target 'Framework' do
  shared
end

target 'FrameworkTests' do
  shared
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Go to your test logs in Derived data folder:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APP_BUILD_FOLDER/Logs/Test
```

You will find a `.xcresult` test result bundle, right-click it and choose `Show package contents` and in `1_Test/Diagnostics` folder, you should find run/crash log for your tests.

This log will give you an exact cause of your fail, you can post it here if you don't know what to do with it after you find it, we will help you :-)

Without this log, cause of your issue could be literally anything, since this is rather generic xcbuild fail message.

Comment: thanks for this, it helps me read the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

Oky, thx for logs this should fix your issue:

```
target 'Framework' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.13.1'

  target 'FrameworkTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.13.1'
  end

end
```

You don't have the `RealmSwift` library installed for your test target in pods, only for your app, as you can tell from log:

```
...Library not loaded: @rpath/Realm.framework/Realm referenced from...MyFrameworkTests.xctest...
```

Add code above to your podfile and run `pod update` :-)

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work. Please check my question again for an example where you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you doing `inherit! :search_paths`? That should not be needed in this case. Try to remove it and `pod update`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar modification helped me.

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Framework' do

  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.13.1'

end

target 'FrameworkTests' do

  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.13.1'

end
```

Feel free to use "def" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907073/1401067)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue recently when attempting to run our UI Tests target after our min deployment target was updated from 11.0 to 13.2, which failed immediately on launch. Oddly enough, updating the target all the way up to 12.4 worked just fine, but anything >= 13.0 resulted in the error

```
The bundle "MyAppUITests" couldn't be loaded. Try reinstalling the bundle.
```

The single change that resolved it (beyond ensuring that deployment target was set consistently across all targets, and in the Podfile) was to clear out the value we had listed in the `BUNDLE_LOADER` Build Setting within our UI Test Target.

Before:

```
BUNDLE_LOADER = "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp";
```

After:

```
BUNDLE_LOADER = "";
```