# No such module SwipeMenuViewController Error in Swift

Tags: swift, podfile

So I was working on a personal project and wanted to use SwipeMenuViewController and installed it but when I try to run my project on Xcode it gives me an error and says [No such module 'SwipeMenuViewController']

I do not know why it is saying that since I was able to install SwipeMenuViewController.

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
def shared_pods
    pod 'SwiftChart'
    pod 'Charts'
    pod 'SwipeMenuViewController'
end

target 'StocksSim' do
        shared_pods
end
```

Comment: Your target syntax seems off... Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907073/14351818

Comment: Thank you, I updated my pod file but I still get the same error. No such module SwipeMenuViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing Xcode, delete derived data (`Command` + `Shift` + `K`), and reinstalling pods.

Comment: That solved my first problem but now I have another problem lol. Problem -> No such module 'SwiftChart', I have it installed through pod install.

Comment: Comment all the pods and fire (pod install), then remove derived data and re-install pod after undoing the comments.